# Tensorflow check which examples are predicted correctly and which incorrectly (kind of confusion matrix)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have build 2 different models, and I wanna check if the 2 models make the same mistakes (incorrectly classify the same examples) or if the make different mistakes. The dataset have only 2 labels Positive/Negative.

Essentially I want a confusion matrix of the sort

# num examples both models predict correctly 
# num examples Model A predicts correctly but Model B incorrectly 
 # num examples Model B predicts correctly but Model A incorrectly 
# num examples both models predict incorrectly

I.e. say example #1 in the dataset is predicted correctly by model A but incorrectly by model B. And example #2 is predicted incorrectly by both, and example #2 predicted correctly by both. Byt "predicted correctly" I mean if the label was Negative I predicted Negative, and if the label was Positive I predicted Positive.

Expected result:
`1|1|0|1`

Comment: This is a bit broad. What did you try already? I see multiple questions in the `Related` section.

Comment: @Framester all related question I saw are, if you have only 1 model find TP/FP/FN/TN, now if you have 2 different models to see if you got same or different errors. I could not find an answer, and don't want to reinvent the wheel. I took a look at the sci-kit library documentation but didn't find a way to do it. I updated my question a bit

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the models are not huge and you can fit them both in memory at the same time, you could initialize both (all layers, weights, etc), load trained values on both, then set up a testing method that performs inference on batches and checks for Positive/Negative on each model. Given 2 vectors of Positives/Negatives corresponding to the same test values, you could create a compound vector.

By considering a **Positive** as a **1**, and a **Negative** as a **0**, you could do:

```
vectorCompound = vectorModel1 + 2*vectorModel2
```

This way, you could collect values in `vectorCompound`:

- 0: Both Negative
- 1: Model 1 is positive, model 2 is negative
- 2: Model 2 is positive, model 1 is negative
- 3: Both Positive
  From there, creating the matrix should be straightforward.